# In an eclipse RCP application, can you define a perspective in your pluginCustomization file?

Tags: java, eclipse-rcp, perspective

I would like to be able to define a perspective in my Eclipse RCP application without writing a java class for it. This would allowing me to change that perspective without recompiling the source and remove an unnecessary java class.

At the moment I do have a Perspective defined in a java class, and if I want to modify it without recompilation I can save it with a different name, export the preferences to a `.epf` file (from within my running application) and paste that `_persp=` line into my application `pluginCustomization.ini`, specified at runtime with `-Declipse.pluginCustomization=`.

This works, but I'm unable to get these copied perspectives to appear in the extras bar using `org.eclipse.ui/PERSPECTIVE_BAR_EXTRAS`, such xml perspectives are almost impossible to edit, since they are all on one line, and I still have an unwanted java class hanging around that I don't use.

- So, in an eclipse RCP application, is there a way define a perspective in your pluginCustomization file without it being backed by a java class?

  - If so, can you define the `_persp=` line with respect to a file, containing nicely formatted `xml` code, or are you stuck with *everythingcompactedononeline*?
- Alternatively, are there any other ways to achieve what I want?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure, if it is something what you are looking for, but you may want to try to create your own extension point (see http://www.vogella.com/articles/EclipseExtensionPoint/article.html) for example. In this case you could look something like this:

```
 <extension-point id="my.perspectives" name="perspectives" schema="perspectives.exsd"/>
```

with one element "perspective" which has an "id" attribute, of "identifier" type and "org.eclipse.ui.perspectives/perspective/@id" as a reference (or you could make it just a "string" type, if you don't want to be bound to any eclipse identifiers).

In your plugin.xml, then add something like this:

```
<extension
         point="my.perspectives">
<perspective id="my.perpsective.id"/>
</extension>
```

Then you could process your extension point as follows:

```
for (IConfigurationElement element: Platform.getExtensionRegistry().getConfigurationElementsFor("my.perspectives")) {
  String perspectiveId = element.getAttribute("id");
}
```

And do whatever you want to do with your perspective id. Hope that helps.